# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm following a YT tutorial, and I feel I've copied the code exactly, but keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: Caught AttributeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Connor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "C:\Users\Connor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\Connor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\Connor\OneDrive\Python\Kaggle\Facial Keypoint Detecetion\dataset.py", line 21, in __getitem__
    image = np.array(self.data.iloc[index, 30].split()).astype(np.float32)
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Below is the full code:

```
class FacialKeypointDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, train=True, transform=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.category_names = ['left_eye_center_x', 'left_eye_center_y', 'right_eye_center_x', 'right_eye_center_y', 'left_eye_inner_corner_x', 'left_eye_inner_corner_y', 'left_eye_outer_corner_x', 'left_eye_outer_corner_y', 'right_eye_inner_corner_x', 'right_eye_inner_corner_y', 'right_eye_outer_corner_x', 'right_eye_outer_corner_y', 'left_eyebrow_inner_end_x', 'left_eyebrow_inner_end_y', 'left_eyebrow_outer_end_x', 'left_eyebrow_outer_end_y', 'right_eyebrow_inner_end_x', 'right_eyebrow_inner_end_y', 'right_eyebrow_outer_end_x', 'right_eyebrow_outer_end_y', 'nose_tip_x', 'nose_tip_y', 'mouth_left_corner_x', 'mouth_left_corner_y', 'mouth_right_corner_x', 'mouth_right_corner_y', 'mouth_center_top_lip_x', 'mouth_center_top_lip_y', 'mouth_center_bottom_lip_x', 'mouth_center_bottom_lip_y']
        self.transform = transform
        self.train = train

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self.train:
            image = np.array(self.data.iloc[index, 30].split()).astype(np.float32)
            labels = np.array(self.data.iloc[index, :30].tolist())
            labels[np.isnan(labels)] = -1
        else:
            image = np.array(self.data.iloc[index, 1].split()).astype(np.float32)
            labels = np.zeros(30)

        ignore_indices = labels == -1
        labels = labels.reshape(15, 2)

        if self.transform:
            image = np.repeat(image.reshape(96, 96, 1), 3, 2).astype(np.uint8)
            augmentations = self.transform(image=image, keypoints=labels)
            image = augmentations["image"]
            labels = augmentations["keypoints"]

        labels = np.array(labels).reshape(-1)
        labels[ignore_indices] = -1

        return image, labels.astype(np.float32)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ds = FacialKeypointDataset(csv_file="data/train_4.csv", train=True, transform=config.train_transforms)
    loader = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

    for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(loader):
        plt.imshow(x[0][0].detach().cpu().numpy(), cmap='gray')
        plt.plot(y[0][0::2].detach().cpu().numpy(), y[0][1::2].detach().cpu().numpy(), "go")
        plt.show()
```

In the tutorial it has the same lines of code, but no error. Here is the link to the Gituhub:
https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/tree/master/ML/Kaggles/Facial%20Keypoint%20Detection%20Competition

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: The data at that specific location `self.data.iloc[index, 30]` will have been of type `str` in the tutorial, but in your case it is a `numpy.float64`, which does not have a `.split()` method like a string does. Without further code, or some example data that reproduces the error, it is impossible to say what you are doing wrong/differently to cause that difference. A likely candidate are the inputs you are using, or how you are reading them.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to expect that the value returned by `self.data.iloc[index, 30]` will always be a string.

That might be ok for the project you are basing your code on, but if you pass a csv file that has floats instead of strings it will result on the error that you got.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data to float with `.astype(np.float32)` first. For example,

```
self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
self.data = self.data.astype(np.float32)
```

Or

```
self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, dtype=np.float64)
```

If you got error, it means your csv_file has data type like strings, and this program cannot be used on your input data.